# Defining an atlas on sphere $\Bbb S^2$ with two charts in spherical coordinate

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

> How can we define an atlas on the sphere $\Bbb S^2$ with two charts in
> spherical coordinate instead of stereographic projection?
>
> $$\Bbb S^2=\{(\sin b\cos a, \sin b\sin a, \cos
>  b)=(x,y,z):x^2+y^2+z^2=1, 0\leq a \leq 2\pi$$$$\text{ and }0\leq b
>  \leq \pi\}.$$

I consider the following charts? Are they correct?

$F\colon \Bbb S^2\backslash \{(1,0,0)\} := U\longrightarrow (0, 2\pi) \times (0,\pi)$
where  $U =\{(\sin b \cos a, \sin b \sin a, \cos b ): 0 < a < 2\pi \text{ and } 0< b <\pi\}$;

and

$F\colon \Bbb S^2\backslash \{(-1,0,0)\} := V\longrightarrow (-\pi ,\pi) \times (0,\pi)$
where  $V =\{(\sin b \cos a, \sin b \sin a, \cos b ): -\pi < a < \pi \text{  and } 0< b <\pi\}$

Comment: Each of those formulas omits a closed half of a great circle; together they do not cover the sphere.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew, But I did not understand what you mean, would you please define two charts in spherical coordinates. In fact, I just omitted two points (1,0,0) and (-1,0,0) from S^2 not closed half of a great circle. so $U$ and $V$ cover S^2. May you help me to compute correctly?

Comment: I did like the stereographic projection that we omit the north and south poles

Comment: _Each chart_ omits a closed half of a great circle. _Together_ the charts do not cover the entire sphere, but omit the two poles. That is, the points $(0, 0, \pm1)$ are in neither of your proposed charts, regardless of the stated domains. <> The stereographic projection maps, by contrast, _each_ omit only one point, and together they cover the sphere. <> I commented rather than answering because I'm not sure what is your goal. Do you want to cover the entire sphere with just two "spherical coordinates-type" charts? If so, you'll need to pick different axes for the two charts.

Comment: Thank you again, Andrew. Yes, I want to cover the entire sphere with just two "spherical coordinates-type" charts if it is possible. otherwise, I don't know how can I write the rest of the charts to cover sphere. In fact, with the above charts that I wrote, we cover a great circle passing axis "x". but we need two charts to cover the great circle passing axis "z". I don't know how can I write it.

Comment: I consider coordinates  "   | -----  "  axis   "|"     is   "z "    and  axis  " ----"   is   "y"

Comment: I mean what are the variations of "a" and "b" to cover the axis "z"?  which  angles pass   the points (0,0,±1)

Comment: it seems to me we must change "b" but I don't know-how

Comment: nicrot000's answer contains a good hint: "can you define a second chart's inverse as above, such that the missing half circles are disjoint?" <> Another hint: Make a sketch of the existing half-circles to see why they do not "work", and sketch two suitable half-circles. Then you can take one of your charts and simply _permute the coordinates_ to make it suit your purposes.

Comment: Thank you so much Andrew,

Answer (score 2):

To answer your actual question: No, these do not cover the whole sphere (cf. Andrew's comment).

In fact, it is better to write down the charts' inverses. So consider the map (corresponding to your first chart):
$$
\phi_1:(0,2\pi)\times(0,\pi)\to\mathbb{S}^2,~(a,b)\mapsto(\sin b\cos a,\sin b\sin a,\cos b).
$$
Can you see why this map' range is not $\mathbb{S}^2\backslash\{(1,0,0)\}$? Or rather, can you see the missing half circle that Andrew was talking about?

In a next step, can you define a second chart's inverse as above, such that the missing half circles are disjoint?

Comment: Thank you, So what is the solution?

Comment: May you refer to a book or paper or guide me?

Comment: My mistake is defining the domain \phi_1 and \phi_2 as the inverse of charts? Am I right?

Comment: No, charts are usually defined as maps on the manifold, mapping into some (open subset of some) $\mathbb{R}^n$. The inverse of a chart is usually called local parameterization and in this particular case writing down the local parameterization is easier (namely using spherical coordinates). Your mistake is mainly that what you call $U$ (or $V$) in your question is not the sphere with only one point removed, but with $a$ and $b$ in the intervals $(-\pi,\pi)$ and $(0,\pi)$, respectively, you obtain the sphere with a half-circle removed, instead.

Comment: Yes, I made mistakes.  but we need two charts to cover the great circle passing axis "z".

Comment: what are intervals for  "a" and "b" to cover axis "z"?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "cover axis z". The $z$-axis in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is not a subset of $\mathbb{S}^2$.

Comment: However, the map $\phi_1$ I wrote down covers all of $\mathbb{S}^2$ with that half-circle removed which starts in $(0,0,1)$, passes through $(1,0,0)$ and ends in $(0,0,-1)$. Can you see that? If not, try to make a sketch. Particularly, the endpoint of that half-circle are also not in the range of $\phi_1$ which is why you cannot obtain a suitable $\phi_2$ by adjusting the angle intervals.

Comment: So as a second half-cicle that is disjoint from the first one, what first comes to my mind ist the one starting in $(0,1,0)$, passing through $(-1,0,0)$ and ending in $(0,-1,0)$. Try to make a sketch of this one as well and you will see why it is disjoint from the first half-circle. Now you can start defining $\phi_2$, also given by spherical coordinates. Therefore you can take the formula of $\phi_1$ (with the same domain intervals) and by interchanging the components and possibly adding some $-$-signs you can achieve your goal.

Comment: Thank you, Nicroto.